# onclick open window and specific size

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link like this:

```
<a href="/index2.php?option=com_jumi&amp;fileid=3&amp;Itemid=11" onclick="window.open(this.href,'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,')
```

I want the new opening window to open in a specific size. How do I specify the height and width?

Answer (score 212, accepted):

```
<a href="/index2.php?option=com_jumi&amp;fileid=3&amp;Itemid=11"
   onclick="window.open(this.href,'targetWindow',
                                   `toolbar=no,
                                    location=no,
                                    status=no,
                                    menubar=no,
                                    scrollbars=yes,
                                    resizable=yes,
                                    width=SomeSize,
                                    height=SomeSize`);
 return false;">Popup link</a>
```

Where width and height are pixels without units (width=400 not width=400px).

In most browsers it will not work if it is not written without line breaks, once the variables are setup have everything in one line:

```
<a href="/index2.php?option=com_jumi&amp;fileid=3&amp;Itemid=11" onclick="window.open(this.href,'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=SomeSize,height=SomeSize'); return false;">Popup link</a>
```

Comment: You'll also want to swap the last ")" character for ");return false;" to prevent the original link being opened in addition to the popup.

Comment: An old one but I found this via search so corrected answer as per reply from @AndrewSpear

Comment: @Larry Hipp how can i change it to fit the size of the screen?

Comment: @IdhamChoudry Just remove the width/height properties and it will automatically take all the available space. I believe setting `width=100vw, height=100vh` would work too.

Comment: For me it works, but ONE IMPORTANT THING - you should not use line breaks in the body of your function, as in the example above. I've removed line breaks and it worked for me.

Comment: for me, the line brakes didn't matter - just the width didn't work w/o the height parameter as well ...

Answer (score 33):

```
window.open ("http://www.javascript-coder.com",
"mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=250");
```

from

http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

:]

Answer (score 21):

```
window.open('http://somelocation.com','mywin','width=500,height=500');
```

Answer (score 14):

Just add them to the parameter string.

```
window.open(this.href,'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=350,height=250')
```

Answer (score 11):

```
<a style="cursor:pointer"
  onclick=" window.open('http://YOUR.URL.TARGET','',' scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,width=500, resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no')">Your text</a>
```

Comment: Although I do ask, what does this add to all the already given answers?

Answer (score 3):

These are the best practices from [Mozilla Developer Network's window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open#Best_practices) page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var windowObjectReference = null; // global variable

function openFFPromotionPopup() {
  if(windowObjectReference == null || windowObjectReference.closed)
  /* if the pointer to the window object in memory does not exist
     or if such pointer exists but the window was closed */

  {
    windowObjectReference = window.open("http://www.spreadfirefox.com/",
   "PromoteFirefoxWindowName", "resizable,scrollbars,status");
    /* then create it. The new window will be created and
       will be brought on top of any other window. */
  }
  else
  {
    windowObjectReference.focus();
    /* else the window reference must exist and the window
       is not closed; therefore, we can bring it back on top of any other
       window with the focus() method. There would be no need to re-create
       the window or to reload the referenced resource. */
  };
}
</script>

<p><a
 href="http://www.spreadfirefox.com/"
 target="PromoteFirefoxWindowName"
 onclick="openFFPromotionPopup(); return false;" 
 title="This link will create a new window or will re-use an already opened one"
>Promote Firefox adoption</a></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Anyone looking for a quick Vue file component, here you go:

```
// WindowUrl.vue

<template>
    <a :href="url" :class="classes" @click="open">
        <slot></slot>
    </a>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            url: String,
            width: String,
            height: String,
            classes: String,
        },
        methods: {
            open(e) {
                // Prevent the link from opening on the parent page.
                e.preventDefault();

                window.open(
                    this.url,
                    'targetWindow',
                    `toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,width=${this.width},height=${this.height}`
                );
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Usage:

```
<window-url url="/print/shipping" class="btn btn-primary" height="250" width="250">
    Print Shipping Label
</window-url>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using function in typescript

```
openWindow(){
    //you may choose to deduct some value from current screen size
    let height = window.screen.availHeight-100;
    let width = window.screen.availWidth-150;
    window.open("http://your_url",`width=${width},height=${height}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a button to refer to another window with a single click

```
<Button onClick={() => {window.open("https://www.google.com")}}>
    Button Description
</Button>
```