# How to open a page in a new tab (google chrome issue)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scriptmanager

I open my page in a new tab through the following code :

```
String js = "window.open('" + page + "'" + ", '_blank');";

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Open", js, true);
```

but in `Google chrome` it opens in a new window rather than in a new tab !

How to make it open in a new tab or even maximized ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't force the browser to open a tab instead of a window. That's up to the browser. I'm using Chrome 24.0.1312.57m, and all links, whether `_blank` or `_new`, open in *tabs*, not new windows.

Comment: then how to make this window maximized initially

Comment: @just_name: You can't have it maximized, but you can choose a size. It can look maximized if you set it to the size of the screen. Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2157180/388916

Answer (score 1):

Javascript code cannot ensure that.It depends on the browser settings of the user whether a page will open in a new window or tab.