# Open new window

Tags: javascript, php

I am using php.

```
function as_pdf_link( $strContent )
{
    global $wp_query;

    $strHtml = '
        <div id="aspdf">
            <a href="' . get_bloginfo('wpurl') . '/wp-content/plugins/as-pdf/generate.php?post=' . $wp_query->post->ID .'">
                <span>' . stripslashes( get_option( 'as_pdf_linktext' ) ) . '</span>
            </a>     
        </div>';

    return $strContent . $strHtml;
}
```

When user clicks link, generate.php will be processed.

I would like to show the result returned from these PHP code with new window using javascript.

How should I do for this?

Comment: just add `target="new"` to your anchor (<a>) tag?

Answer (score 1):

## Use `target="_blank"`

```
<a target="_blank" href="' . get_bloginfo('wpurl') . '/wp-content/plugins/as-pdf/generate.php?post=' . $wp_query->post->ID .'">
            <span>' . stripslashes( get_option( 'as_pdf_linktext' ) ) . '</span>
        </a>
```

## Have a look [target="_blank" vs. target="_new"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964130/target-blank-vs-target-new)

Open in new window with javascript: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/70wjgxe7/)

```
onclick="return fun(this);"
```

function:

```
function fun(that){
    console.log(that.href);
    window.open(that.href, "New Window", "height=600,width=600");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It was displayed at new tab in current opening browser. I want to display it with new opening browser.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how fancy you want to get...

**Really simple solution:** add:

```
target="_blank"
```

to the link tag,

**More complicated solution:**

Add an onclick handler to the element: Such as is explained here:[onclick open window and specific size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157180/onclick-open-window-and-specific-size)

**Best practices solution:**

Write a separate javascript file and bind to the link in question from there.