# Open a static html in a new window

Tags: javascript, html, struts

I have a struts application. I want to open a static html page in a new window using window.open(). I tried following but it does not work.

```
<input type="button" id="" value="Edit" 
        onclick="window.open('primaryLicense.html','Select License Status',
                             'height=400,width=400');" />
```

Please help

Comment: Why not? What happens? What do you see in the dev tools?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157180/onclick-open-window-and-specific-size

Comment: its working fine...http://jsfiddle.net/r2hyakq0/

Comment: THe URL is http://localhost:7001/HotSheet/primaryLicense.html and there is an error called Error 404--Not Found

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
window.open(url,'_blank');
window.open(url);
```