# Auto Resize Popup

Tags: html, popup, popupwindow, autosize

I have looked all over the play and cannot find any scripts that work correctly, so this was my last resort.

I am trying to automatically resize this popup window that I found online because at the moment it is showing nicely on some browsers / computers but really bad on others.

My Code:

```
<a href="http://mickyd.net/radio" onclick="javascript:void window.open('http://mickyd.net/radio/','1448219368924','toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,left=0,top=0');return false;">Radio</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157180/onclick-open-window-and-specific-size)?

Comment: no, @Jdsfighter that is not for auto sizing the window...

Comment: That question answers how to open the window with a specific set of dimensions.

Comment: I do not want that, I want it to automatically resize the popup window according the the HTML that is in it. @Jdsfighter

Comment: `according the the HTML that is in it`

But how are you denoting what size the window should be? Generally webpages do not dictate the size of the window. You can't really autosize to content that isn't meant to be autosized.