# Can anyone suggest me how to integrate slack.com login page into a pop up window in my JSP file on click of a button

Tags: jsp, popupwindow

I have a jsp file in my project and I have defined a button as soon as user clicks on it it should fire a pop up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.open` to accomplish this.

See this [onclick open window and specific size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157180/onclick-open-window-and-specific-size) for details.

### See also

- [JavaScript open in a new window, not tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab)