# to open a jsp in new window with custom size

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp

I am sending some data from one page to another via controller , for sending data I am using hidden element.

```
$(form).attr("method","POST");
$(form).attr("target","_blank");
$(form).attr("action","url")
```

I want to open the "url" in new window with custom size.
I have seen many posts regarding this but not getting any proper solution.

Comment: try : `var myWindow = window.open(url, "_blank", "width=200,height=100");`

Comment: I can not use window.open(), as I am sending data from js to controller using POST

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157180/onclick-open-window-and-specific-size you will get some idea