# How to open application in specific width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm working on chatbot application using react. I want to open the application in specific width that is 762px. Then the user can shrink or grow the screen size, then the application will behave in a responsive manner(adapting to the screen size made available by the user). Just like how the Amazon chat bot works.

Comment: Not knowing what amazon chat bot is, I assume you just [open a window with the width supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157180/onclick-open-window-and-specific-size), and have the target html handle it like regular responsive css?

Comment: Yeah, i'm doing that right now. But thought about what could be a better approach.

Comment: I don't think there is. You have limited APIs, i.e. `window.open` with some parameters, and responsive CSS. What else is there? I could be mistaken but not sure what you're asking if it's not just that.