# How can i prevent window.open() from using full sized screen because the current window is full sized?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, window.open

So i want a popup window to appear with a certain size when i click a button in my chrome extension, it works fine when the current window isn't full screen but if the current is full screen window.open() also opens a full sized window and redirects me to it. That isn't what i want. I also tried it with chrome.windows.create but i had the same problem. Also there are no errors. How can i make it so that it isn't full sized and just a popup with the specified height on top of the current window? This is my code:

```js
$(".paypal-login").on("click", () => {
  const windowFeatures = "left=0,top=0,width=320,height=320";
  window.open('https://www.paypal.com/signin?country.x=NL&locale.x=nl_NL', 'popup', windowFeatures)
})
```

I added 2 photos, 1 where my current window is full screen and one where i made it a little bit smaller.

EDIT: Im on MacOS[image: full sized screen][image: smaller window]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [onclick open window and specific size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157180/onclick-open-window-and-specific-size)

Comment: @WhiteWizard nope didn't work, i got exactly the same

Comment: Try `const windowFeatures = "popup";`

Comment: @Konrad doesn't work it creates a normal tab in the current window